# Blank page with a title before appendices

Tags: table-of-contents, formatting, appendices

I am using document class `report`. To ensure the word "appendix" appears in my table of contents, I have used the following:

```
  \usepackage[title,titletoc,toc, page]{appendix}
```

and

```
  \begin{appendices}
  \include{SomeAp1}
  \clearpage
  \include{SomeAp2} 
  \end{appendices}
```

This adds the word appendix to my table of contents. However, it also creates a extra page with the heading "Appendices" right before the first appendix. Therefore, instead of showing something like the following in TOC:

Appendices   page 11
Appendix A   page 11
Appendix B   page 17

I get

Appendices   page 10
Appendix A   page 11
Appendix B   page 17

ADDED:

```
\documentclass{report}

 \usepackage{comment} 
 \usepackage{amssymb} 
 \usepackage{xspace}
 \usepackage{graphicx}
 \usepackage{amsmath}
 \usepackage{enumerate}
 \usepackage{amssymb}
 \usepackage{multirow}

 \usepackage[letterpaper,left=1in,right=1in,top=1in,bottom=1in]{geometry}
 \usepackage{tocbibind}
 \usepackage[title,titletoc,toc,page]{appendix}
 \usepackage[doublespacing]{setspace}


 \usepackage{hyperref}
 \hypersetup{
      colorlinks,
      citecolor=black,
      filecolor=black,
      linkcolor=black,
      urlcolor=black}

  \setcounter{secnumdepth}{3}

  \begin{document}
   \pagenumbering{roman} 
   \setcounter{page}{2}

    \include{Abstract}
    \include{Acknowledgements}
    \tableofcontents
    \listoffigures

   \clearpage
   \pagenumbering{arabic}
   \setcounter{page}{1}

   \include{someChapter}

   \bibliographystyle{plain}               
    \bibliography{MyLib}                      


    \begin{appendices}
    \include{Ap1}
    \clearpage
    \include{Ap2} 
    \end{appendices}                     

     \end{document}
```

ADDED:  I added

```
     \usepackage[toc,titletoc,title]{appendix}
```

instead of

```
     \usepackage[title,titletoc,toc, page]{appendix}
```

And this almost gives me the effect I want, but it has one problem. In table of contents, first Appendix A is mentioned, then appendices, then Appendix B.

Thank you in advance

Comment: Please post a compilable document, not just fragments

Comment: @ChristianHupfer plz see the additions to my question. Thanks for your help

Comment: It seems that you did not do what I said in my answer which was not to use the `toc` option of the `appendix` package. I have edited my answer to make that clearer.

Answer (score 1):

Don't use the `toc` option of the `appendix` package. As the documentation says: "[It] puts a header (e.g., Appendices) into the ToC before listing the Appendices"

As far as I can tell

```
\usepackage[title,titletoc,page]{appendix}
```

gives the result you are after.

Comment: Removing the toc option removes "appendices" from table of contents. I need to have that in table of contents, however, I don't want to have an extra page before the appendices.

Comment: Another point is that if I click the link appendices, it brings me to the page but for some reason under the appendices title, so that I don't see where I am I just have to scroll up to see the title appendices which is somewhat in the middle of the page

Comment: ADDED:  I added  
         \usepackage[toc,titletoc,title]{appendix}
instead of 
         \usepackage[title,titletoc,toc, page]{appendix}
And this almost gives me the effect I want, but it has one problem. In table of contents, first Appendix A is mentioned, then appendices, then Appendix B.

Answer (score 0):

You first need to remove the `page` option to the `appendix` package.  You are then left with the problem described in the documentation of the `appendix` package in "2.1 Known problems": the table of contents code generated by `\begin{appendices}` interacts badly with following `\include` command, resulting in an incorrect ordering in the table of contents.

A workaround is to replace the first `\include{SomeAp1}` after `\begin{appendices}` by `\input{SomeAp1}`:

[image: Sample output]

```
\documentclass{report}

\usepackage{tocbibind}
\usepackage[toc,titletoc,title]{appendix}

\begin{document}
\pagenumbering{roman}
\setcounter{page}{2}

\tableofcontents

\clearpage
\pagenumbering{arabic}
\setcounter{page}{1}

\chapter{Some Chapter}

\begin{appendices}
  \input{Ap1}
\include{Ap2}
\end{appendices}

\end{document}
```

where `Ap1.tex` is

```
\chapter{Appendix 1}

Text.
```

and `Ap2.tex` is

```
\chapter{Appendix 2}

Text.
```