# Report - Change or remove only one chapter heading

Tags: table-of-contents, formatting, chapters

I have the following code in my report document:

```
 \pagenumbering{roman} 
 \setcounter{page}{2}
 \include{Abstract}
 \include{Dedication}
 \include{Acknowledgements}
 \tableofcontents
 ......
```

and the file dedication includes

```
\chapter*{Dedication}
\addcontentsline {toc}{chapter}{Dedication}
To Someone
```

I am using hyperref

```
   \hypersetup{
      colorlinks,
      citecolor=black,
      filecolor=black,
      linkcolor=black,
      urlcolor=black}
```

My question is how I can remove the chapter header only for this file, or perhaps change its setting, while leaving other chapter headings as they are.

If I remove `\chapter*{Dedication}`, I have a problem with TOC, where clicking dedication does not take me to the correct page. Another option would be if I write `\chapter*{To Someone}`, but in this case I need to change the size of chapter header only for this page, and I do not know how.

Your help is greatly appreciated

[Added Code]

```
\documentclass{report}

\usepackage{comment} 
\usepackage{amssymb} 
\usepackage{xspace}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{enumerate}
\usepackage{amssymb}
\usepackage{multirow}

\usepackage[letterpaper,left=1in,right=1in,top=1in,bottom=1in]{geometry}
\usepackage{tocbibind}
\usepackage[title,titletoc,toc,page]{appendix}
\usepackage[doublespacing]{setspace}


\usepackage{hyperref}
\hypersetup{
  colorlinks,
  citecolor=black,
  filecolor=black,
  linkcolor=black,
  urlcolor=black}

\setcounter{secnumdepth}{3}

\begin{document}
 \pagenumbering{roman} 
 \setcounter{page}{2}

  \include{Abstract}
  \include{Dedication}
  \include{Acknowledgements}
  \tableofcontents
  \listoffigures

 \clearpage
 \pagenumbering{arabic}
 \setcounter{page}{1}

 \include{someChapter}

 \bibliographystyle{plain}               
 \bibliography{MyLib}                      


  \begin{appendices}
  \include{Ap1}
  \clearpage
  \include{Ap2} 
  \end{appendices}                     

   \end{document}
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Remove chapter from ToC](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/24275/remove-chapter-from-toc)

Comment: Note that I don't want to remove it from ToC. In fact I want to keep it in TOC as a chapter, however, in the file itself, I would like to either remove or change the chapter heading

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.SX!](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1436) Please make your code compilable (if possible), or at least complete it with `\documentclass{...}`, the required `\usepackage`'s, `\begin{document}`, and `\end{document}`. That may seem tedious to you, but think of the extra work it represents for TeX.SX users willing to give you a hand. Help them help you: remove that one hurdle between you and a solution to your problem.

Comment: Thanks. I have another open question with the code of document which is at https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/410651/blank-page-with-a-title-before-appendices

Comment: @MelanieA: What about `\cleardoublepage \phantomsection \chapter*{Dedication} \addcontentsline{toc}{chapter}{Dedication}`?

Comment: @Werner I tried adding your suggestion to beginning of my Dedication file. The output still contains the chapter header.

Comment: @MelanieA: And I assume that chapter header is not on the first page of the chapter, but on subsequent pages within the dedication... and may even reference what preceded it (like the Abstract)...?

Comment: Plz see the revised code. I have separate files for each of dedication, abstract, etc.  Inside the dedication file, I have \chapter*{Dedication} \addcontentsline{toc}{chapter}{Dedication}    Followed by the name of the person and at the end \endinput

Comment: I am open to any types of suggestions that helps me have a page where I just add a name and the page shows up in my table of contents as a chapter.

Comment: @Werner I think you misinterpreted the question. The question is about having a working link in the PDF without the actual heading (so without the use of `\chapter*`).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Please try the following:

```
\documentclass{report}

\begin{filecontents}{Dedication.tex}
%\chapter*{Dedication}
\cleardoublepage\phantomsection
\addcontentsline {toc}{chapter}{Dedication}%
To Someone
\end{filecontents}

\usepackage{comment} 
\usepackage{amssymb} 
\usepackage{xspace}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{enumerate}
\usepackage{amssymb}
\usepackage{multirow}

\usepackage[letterpaper,left=1in,right=1in,top=1in,bottom=1in]{geometry}
\usepackage{tocbibind}
\usepackage[title,titletoc,toc,page]{appendix}
\usepackage[doublespacing]{setspace}


\usepackage{hyperref}
\hypersetup{
  colorlinks,
  citecolor=black,
  filecolor=black,
  linkcolor=black,
  urlcolor=black}

\setcounter{secnumdepth}{3}

\begin{document}
 \pagenumbering{roman} 
 \setcounter{page}{2}

  %\include{Abstract}
  \include{Dedication}
  % \include{Acknowledgements}
  \tableofcontents
  \listoffigures

 \clearpage
 \pagenumbering{arabic}
 \setcounter{page}{1}

 % \include{someChapter}

 \bibliographystyle{plain}               
 \bibliography{MyLib}                      


  \begin{appendices}
  % \include{Ap1}
  \clearpage
  % \include{Ap2}
  \end{appendices}                     

   \end{document}
```

The stuff between `\begin{filecontents}` and `\end{filecontents}` should be the contents of your "Dedication.tex".